# Print CSS and JS files in a servlet

Tags: servlets

Here is my servlet code:

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try
{
 out = response.getWriter();
 out.println("<html>");
 out.println("<head>");
 out.println("<title>Servlet EmpresaVuelos</title>");
     out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/estiloPrincipal.css' />");
     out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/ext-all.css' />");
     out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/ext-base.<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>'/>");
     out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/ext-all-debug.<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>' />");            
     out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/prueba.<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>'/>");                                                   
 out.println("</head>");
 out.println("<body>");
     out.println("<img src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/4.jpg' ></img>");
     out.println("<div class='bordeado' style='width:100px;height:100px;' />");
 out.println("</body>");
 out.println("</html>");           
}
catch(IOException io)
{

}
```

I would like to know what I get a blank page? When I remove all the link and script tags, the image in the body is rendered.

Comment: Did you check the source in your browser as well? Btw: I think your code does not compile, you did not escape the double quotes surrounding `title="JavaScript...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing scripts / css one by one, there must be some problem there that messes up the presentation of the HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/ext-base.<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>'/>");
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/ext-all-debug.<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>' />");            
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/prueba.<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>'/>");
```

You're using `<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>` as JavaScript file extension. This is utterly wrong. You've to use just `js`:

```
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/ext-base.js'></script>");
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/ext-all-debug.js'></script>");            
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/Web_Modulo_1/recursos/prueba.js'></script>");
```

*(note that I fixed the self-closing `<script>` tag as well as that may otherwise break in certain browsers)*

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've a bigger design problem here: in a properly designed JSP/Servlet web application, all the HTML is been placed in JSP files, not in Servlets (and from the other side on, all the Java code is been placed in Servlets, not in JSP files).

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: Thankx for all the answers !. I know that I shouldn't be doing things like that, but for instance... How can I redirect to a certain jsp file but before stablish certain params ?... Coz I have downloaded a lot of jsp books but I can't find the way... Romario... I will try what you say while I wait answers... I'll post you back as soon as posible...

Answer (score 0):

This is a little weird: `<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>'` and also you have to close your JavaScripts with `</script>` whether you are using src or just inline code.